# consuming angular directives from ember

Tags: angularjs, architecture, ember.js, components, angularjs-directive

From my experience using both, angular directives allow much better composability and reuse than ember components, which becomes especially apparent when nesting components.  For people who must use ember, does anyone have an approach to consuming angular directives from ember?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible, but also I'm curious what limitations you ran into with Ember components? I've heard similar things in the past from folk migrating to Ember from Angular that didn't quite turn out totally true but you might also be totally right.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'm working on a stackoverflow post with explicit details.  I'll let you know via a new comment here when it's ready.  Thanks so much for the reply.  Awesome to see such a lightning fast answer from a core team member :-)

Comment: The question I'm writing is different, but one issue I currently have is that to nest components together, you currently must override a private framework method ( _yield ): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158948/how-to-access-parent-component-scope-from-a-child-components-scope-in-ember

Comment: Here is the question I have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854860/declarative-ember-component-which-passes-in-a-list-of-objects-to-be-rendered-b  - thanks for taking a look Alex!