# Declarative ember component which passes in a list of objects to be rendered / bound, while passing state that nested components can access?

Tags: api, architecture, ember.js, components, handlebars.js

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to build an ember component which has nested components which are rendered as a list based on an input list, while also allowing state to be passed in which is accessible from the nested components.

This is easy in angular:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="angular-accordion">
<head>
    <style>
        .angular-accordion-header {
            background-color: #999;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 0;
            line-height: 14px;
            -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
            border-top-left-radius: 5px;
            border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .angular-accordion-container {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .angular-accordion-pane {
            padding: 2px;
        }

        .angularaccordionheaderselected {
            background-color: #bbb;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .angular-accordion-header:hover {
            text-decoration: underline !important;
        }

        .angularaccordionheaderselected:hover {
            text-decoration: underline !important;
        }

        .angular-accordion-pane-content {
            padding: 5px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
            border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
            -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        }

        .loading {
            opacity: .2;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">


<div style="height: 90%; width: 100%; margin: 0;" ng-controller="outerController">

    <div class="angular-accordion-header" ng-click="fakeXhrService.load()">
        Click here to simulate loading new data.
    </div>
    <angular-accordion list-of-accordion-pane-objects="outerControllerData" loading="fakeXhrService.isLoading()">
        <pane>
            <pane-header ng-class="{loading:loading}">{{accordionPaneObject.firstName}}</pane-header>
            <pane-content>{{accordionPaneObject.lastName}}</pane-content>
        </pane>
    </angular-accordion>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    angular.module('angular-accordion', [])
            .factory('fakeXhrService', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
                var loading = false,
                    fakeXhrService;

                fakeXhrService = {
                    load: function() {
                        loading = true;

                        $timeout(function() {
                            loading = false;
                        }, 2000);
                    },
                    isLoading: function() {
                        return loading;
                    }
                };

                return fakeXhrService;
            }])
            .directive('angularAccordion', function() {
                var template = '';

                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    transclude: true,
                    replace: true,
                    template: '<div>' +
                            '<div ng-transclude class="angular-accordion-container" ng-repeat="accordionPaneObject in listOfAccordionPaneObjects" ng-cloak></div>' +
                            '</div>',
                    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
                        var panes = [];

                        this.addPane = function(pane) {
                            panes.push(pane);
                        };
                    }],
                    scope: {
                        listOfAccordionPaneObjects: '=',
                        loading: '='
                    }
                };
            })
            .directive('pane', function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    transclude: true,
                    require: '^angularAccordion',
                    replace: true,
                    template: '<div ng-transclude class="angular-accordion-pane"></div>'
                };
            })
            .directive('paneHeader', function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    require: '^angularAccordion',
                    transclude: true,
                    replace: true,
                    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                        controller.addPane(scope);

                        scope.toggle = function() {
                            scope.expanded = !scope.expanded;
                        };
                    },
                    template: '<div ng-transclude class="angular-accordion-header" ng-click="toggle()"></div>'
                };
            })
            .directive('paneContent', function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'EA',
                    require: '^paneHeader',
                    transclude: true,
                    replace: true,
                    template: '<div ng-transclude class="angular-accordion-pane-content" ng-show="expanded"></div>'
                };
            })
            .controller('outerController', ['$scope', 'fakeXhrService', function($scope, fakeXhrService) {
                var people = [],
                    i = 0;

                for(i; i < 10; i++) {
                    people.push({
                        firstName: 'first ' + i.toString(),
                        lastName: 'last ' + i.toString()
                    });
                }

                $scope.outerControllerData = people;

                $scope.fakeXhrService = fakeXhrService;
            }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/NxXAgP8Ba7MK1cz2IGXg?p=preview

Here's my attempt so far doing it in ember:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .ember-accordion-header {
            background-color: #999;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 0;
            line-height: 14px;
            -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
            border-top-left-radius: 5px;
            border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .ember-accordion-pane {
            padding: 2px;
        }

        .ember-accordion-pane-content {
            padding: 5px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
            border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
            -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        }

        .ember-accordion-container {}

        .loading {
            opacity: .2;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/ember-accordion">
    {{#each listOfAccordionPaneObjects itemViewClass="view.emberAccordionItemView"}}
        <div class="ember-accordion-container">
            <div class="ember-accordion-pane">
                {{yield}}
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/ember-accordion-header">
    {{yield}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/ember-accordion-body">
    {{#if parentView.expanded}}
        <div class="ember-accordion-pane-content">
            {{yield}}
        </div>
    {{/if}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    from outside the component: {{test}}
    {{#ember-accordion listOfAccordionPaneObjects=model test=test}}
        {{#ember-accordion-header class="header"}}
            {{firstName}}<br />
            child inner scope test defined directly on the view inside the component: {{view.parentView.specifiedInComponent}}<br />
            child inner scope test passed into the component: {{view.parentView.test}}
        {{/ember-accordion-header}}
        {{#ember-accordion-body class="body"}}
            {{lastName}}<br />
        {{/ember-accordion-body}}
    {{/ember-accordion}}

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{outlet}}
</script>


<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.2.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.2.0/ember.debug.js"></script>
<script>
    var Person = Ember.Object.extend({
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            fullName: function() {
                return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
            }.property()
        }),
        EmberAccordionComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
            // each accordion header/body item, will have a instance of that view.
            // so we can isolate the expanded state for each accordion header/body
            emberAccordionItemView: Ember.View.extend({
                expanded: false,
                specifiedInComponent: 'this works, but how to get it from the property passed to the component?'
            }),
            _yield: function(context, options) {
                var get = Ember.get,
                        view = options.data.view,
                        parentView = this._parentView,
                        template = get(this, 'template');

                if (template) {
                    Ember.assert("A Component must have a parent view in order to yield.", parentView);
                    view.appendChild(Ember.View, {
                        isVirtual: true,
                        tagName: '',
                        _contextView: parentView,
                        template: template,
                        context: get(view, 'context'), // the default is get(parentView, 'context'),
                        controller: get(view, 'controller'), // the default is get(parentView, 'context'),
                        templateData: { keywords: parentView.cloneKeywords() }
                    });
                }
            }
        }),
        EmberAccordionHeaderComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
            classNames: ['ember-accordion-header'],
            classNameBindings: ['expanded'],
            expanded: false,
            click: function() {
                // here we toggle the emberAccordionItemView.expanded property
                this.toggleProperty('parentView.expanded');
                this.toggleProperty('expanded');
            }
        }),
        App = Ember.Application.create(),
        people = [],
        i = 0;

    App.EmberAccordionComponent = EmberAccordionComponent;
    App.EmberAccordionHeaderComponent = EmberAccordionHeaderComponent;

    for(i; i < 10; i++) {
        people.push(Person.create({
            firstName: 'first ' + i.toString(),
            lastName: 'last ' + i.toString()
        }));
    }

    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function() {
            return people;
        }
    });

    App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
        init: function() {
            this._super();

            this.set('test', 'TEST WORKED!');
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/apIYurEN/1/edit

Where I'm stuck is:

1. Why isn't the parameter 'test' accessible inside the ember-accordion-header component?  If I define it directly on the view inside the outer component I can access it.
2. How can I avoid putting view.parentView in front of the parameter I want to access, ie: view.parentView.specifiedInComponent?  This is not simple for api consumers.
3. Why do I have to override a private method of ember to get this far ( _yield ).  Overriding private members is a bad idea since they can change between versions of ember.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You had me at: "This is easy in angular" :P

It's not necessary to override _yield. The default behaviour allows you to access view properties defined in the parentView by using {{view.property}}. When nesting components this means that the properties are passed down recursively. Also you forgot to set `test=test` on the ember-accordion-header component.

Here is a working version: http://jsbin.com/apIYurEN/6/

Comment: Thanks Thomas!  Unfortunately when you don't override yield here, the data you pass in via the list is not accessible via the sub components.  Ie: {{firstName}} no longer renders.

Comment: When you pass in options like so: `{{#ember-accordion var1="hello" var2="world"}}`, var1 and var2 are _per definition_ accessible in the components template. Furthermore I noticed you're calling yield multiple times which apparently isn't allowed (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_layouts). Also I feel like the ember-accordion should be much simpler to define. Now you're yielding it's complete structure, which should really be the concern of the component itself. A solution would be something like this `{{ember-accordion itemBodyPartial="..." itemHeaderPartial=".."}}`.

Comment: unfortunately this solution just isn't a simple to use api.  {{ember-accordion itemBodyPartial="..." itemHeaderPartial=".."}}  It requires the api consumer to know how EMBER.TEMPLATES works, define two new partials, figure out where the wiring for EMBER.TEMPLATES is done, wire them up to EMBER.TEMPLATES, matching the partial ids to the parameters in the component api, and then edit three different files.  Wouldn't you agree the api I proposed is much simpler to use?  You just edit the html and reference the bindings.  That's it!  I'm starting to think ember just isn't cut out for this.

Comment: perhaps what ember needs to get closer to angular in terms of features for components is an ability to inherit scope from a parent component like angular does through 'requires'.

Comment: I think with a components main characteristic being that it is self composed, it makes no sense to access the parent view or make assumptions about it. The component should be provided with all the information that it requires to render. Also I'd assume the "api consumer" (i suppose that would just be a co-developer), to know about partials. Furthermore it's not necessary to figure out "where the wiring goes", in the component template you could just do `{{partial itemBodyPartial}}` (See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_bound-template-names).

Comment: Might be a matter of taste which api is simpler tho:)

Comment: We can also continue the discussion here on the ember discussion forum: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/declarative-ember-component-which-passes-in-a-list-of-objects-to-be-rendered-bound-while-passing-state-that-nested-components-can-access/3724 or on the github issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4056